# String.Format for rounding, can't locate illegal format conversion source error?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I'm writing a program that lets the user input 6 temperature readings, and then either

1. return the highest original values +celcius version
2. return the original values + conversion into the celsius version.

the code where the arrays values are set is here:

```
System.out.print( "Enter Temperature:\t");   //Get the count...
        Temp = LocalInput.nextInt();
        WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount = Temp;
```

the error message that i get is this

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
at p2list.WeeklyReport(p2list.java:102)
at p2list.main(p2list.java:33)"
```

i've also found the exact phrase that gives me trouble:

```
String.format("%.2d", (WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount - 32) * 5 / 9)"
```

i know that the error happens when my `"%._"` doesn't have the right specifier, but all of my variables and arrays are in int, so d should be working

here's the rest of the code:

This is how i set the 1st array:

```
private static  WeatherLocation[] WeatherSpots = new WeatherLocation[6];"
```

This is the class that later arrays use

```
public class WeatherLocations extends WeatherLocation {
    public String LocationID;
    public Integer CatchCount;"

    arrays = WeatherSpots.LoccationID/Catchcount"
```

Here's where the `catchcount` array is set with the user input temperatures

```
int K;
for(K = 0 ; K < 6 ; K++){
    System.out.print( "Enter Temperature:\t");
    Temp = LocalInput.nextInt();
    WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount = Temp;
```

Here's the method where i try to call on the `WeatherSpots[K].catchcount` values to convert to celcius

```
int K= 0;
for(K = 0 ; K < 6 ; K++){
    System.out.println( "" + WeatherSpots[K].LocationID +"\t\t" + WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount + "\t\t" + String.format("%.2f", (WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount - 32) * 5 / 9));
```

What would be causing the error, if my arrays and variables are the proper types for using `string.format`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In

```
String.format("%.2f", (WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount - 32) * 5 / 9)
```

you are trying to print an `int` with a format for `double`s or `float`s. That causes the `IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer`. Since the integer division truncates anyway, it isn't very useful to print an integer with two places after the decimal point. Just divide by the floating point number `9.0` instead of the `int` 9 to get a floating point number that you can format with `%.2f`.

In your

```
String.format("%.2d", (WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount - 32) * 5 / 9)
```

the format `%.2d` is invalid since it doesn't make sense to print integers with places after the decimal point.

Comment: @user1476390: Since this answer solved your problem, you should up-vote Daniel's answer (as I have done) by clicking on the up-arrow to the left of it, and then you should accept it by clicking on the big check mark to the left of it.